# Changing $column and $gutter does not have effect in Bourbon Neat

Tags: sass, bourbon, neat

I'm using Bourbon and Neat, and got everything working as it should, apart from one thing. When I change the values of `$column` and `$gutter` in _grid-setting, nothing changes. Those are the only two variables that don't have any effect.

Changing `$grid-columns` or `$max-width` work as they should, so that confirms that all files are in the right place and get included.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that `grid-settings` is getting imported *before* you `@import neat`? If you try to import it after, it will have already used the default values.

There is some information about that [in the project Readme](https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat#using-neat).

Comment: Yes, it is imported before neat. Also, the other vars I change in `grid-settings` _do_ have impact on the grid. The problem is with just those two variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try flagging them with !global... kind of hacky but it might work.